# Bootstrap4 Navbar collapse button on mobile version is not responding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a website and its navigation bar menu button is not responding when touched whatsoever.
I'm using Bootstrap, and I tried different ways such as `data-target: "navbar-collapse"` items to `#navbar` but nothing works. What is the issue in my code?

```html
<style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</style>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
  <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse"> <span>Menu</span></button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="button navButtons" href="about.html"> Biography </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="button navButtons" href="interiorDesigns.html"> Interior Design </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="button navButtons" href="arts.html"> Arts </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="button navButtons" href="blogs.html"> Blogs </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="button navButtons" href="contact.html"> Contact </a>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <div class="form-group mb-4">
              <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="form-control form-control-underlined">
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Seems like `#navbar` is the wrong id? Correct one would be `#navbarSupportedContent`. Also if you are specifying a class it should start with a period. `.navbar-collapse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when adding links and scripts. You have wrapped its inside a `<style>` tag, which allow you to define some CSS rules directly, but it does not stand for css / js imports.

Then bootstrap has a `brand-logo` class to include your logo, but you do not need to include it as parts of your `<ul>` list if you want to see it always, even if your nav is collapse.

Then you have duplicated `navbar-collapse` which is not right, see my implementation below. And if it is not working yet, try to change your jquery import by including a *not slim* one.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="ndex.html">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Biography <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="interiorDesigns.html">Interior Design</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="arts.html">Arts</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="blogs.html">Blogs</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the suggestion, I'm trying on it and I have a tiny problem that I have white space in my logo, I try to get rid of padding/margin, but it isn't doing anything.. My navbar looks like this on the browser ```[logo              ][biography][blogs]``` instead of ```[logo][biography][blog]``` I tried adjusting width, margin, padding but none worked. any advice on this please?

Comment: If I understand well, the margin which is bothering you is the one from `navbar-brand`. In fact, it has a `margin-right: 1rem;` which you can override by adding an id on this tag, or by overriding the rule as is : `.navbar-brand{ margin-right: 0;}` for example. Is it correct ?